# URL Regex Failing When Adding Query Params

Tags: regex, forms, validation

I have this custom Regex statement to validate websites on my app. I have everything working correctly except one case.

If I use query params in my URL, it doesn't pass the regex.

Here is what I currently have:

`pattern="^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*$"`

Current Output: Fails on URLs such as `http://google.com/hello?world=foo`

Expected Output: Allow query params in the URL.

Comment: Something like this? [`^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*(\?[a-z0-9]*=[a-z0-9]*(&[a-z0-9]*=[a-z0-9]*)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/CXHm4l/1)  It matches the `?=` and then has an optional capture group for the additional `&x=etc`

Comment: Try regexlib (http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=querystring), there's some useful stuff there. I found this pattern that might work for you: (?:(?<scheme>[a-z]+):\/\/)?(?:(?<usern>[a-z0-9_.]*)(?::(?<passw>[a-z0-9_.]*))?@)?(?<domain>(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9_-]+\.?)+|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}))(?::(?<port>[0-9]+))?(?<path>(?:\/[.%a-z0-9_-]*)+)?(?:\?(?<query>(?:&?[][a-z0-9_]+(?:\=?[a-z0-9_;]*)?)+))?(?:#(?<fragment>[a-z0-9_]+))?

Comment: @chrisz this one forces me to have query param. I want it optional

Comment: Just had to add optional to the last capture group: [`^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9#]+\/?)*(\?[a-z0-9]*=[a-z0-9]*(&[a-z0-9]*=[a-z0-9]*)*?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/CXHm4l/2/)

Comment: What developing language are you using on your app?